# Passing URL variables to a class based view

Tags: django, class, listview, url, django-generic-views

I have just started messing with class based views and I would like to be able to access variables from the URL inside my class. But I am having difficulties getting this to work. I saw some answers but they were all so short I found them to be of no help.

Basically I have a url

```
url(r'^(?P<journal_id>[0-9]+)/$',
    views.Journal_Article_List.as_view(), 
    name='Journal_Page'),
```

Then I would like to use `ListView` to display all articles in the particular journal. My article table however is linked to the journal table via a `journal_id`. So I end up doing the following

```
class Journal_Article_List(ListView):
    template_name = "journal_article_list.html"
    model = Articles
    queryset = Articles.objects.filter(JOURNAL_ID = journal_id)
    paginate_by = 12

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Journal_Article_List, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['range'] = range(context["paginator"].num_pages)
        return context
```

The journal_id however is not passed on like it is in functional views. From what I could find on the topic I read I can access the variable using

```
self.kwargs['journal_id']
```

But I’m kind of lost on how I am supposed to do that. I have tried it directly within the class which lets me know that self does not exist or by overwriting get_queryset, in which case it tells me `as_view()` only accepts arguments that are already attributes of the class.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you override `get_queryset`, you can access `journal_id` from the URL in `self.kwargs`:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return Articles.objects.filter(JOURNAL_ID=self.kwargs['journal_id'])
```

You can read more about django’s dynamic filtering [in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering).

Comment: BTW, am I correct in understanding that .as_view() generates an instance of the class I define and that that is also the reason I can't access .self.kwargs in the main bit of the class because it describes the properties of the class and not a specific instance?

Comment: You can't access `self.kwargs` in class attributes because the class is loaded when the server starts, before the request has been made. As you say, `as_view()` returns the callable view used in the url config, but that happens *after* the class is loaded.